# Why will browsers not display my SVG polygon?

Tags: svg, browser

I have created an SVG file to display an icon for an open folder.
It consists of a rectangle for the tab and a rectangle for the backleaf of the folder, with the open leaf represented by a polygon.
Image editors display the intended result, but browsers seem to ignore the polygon.
what am I missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg id="folder_icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
width="90" height="60" viewbox="0 0 90 60" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> 
<g width="50%" height="80%">
  <g id="g3" fill="#ffee77" stroke="#bb7711" stroke-width="2px" opacity="0.7">   
        <g id="g2">
        <rect x="16%" y="1%" rx="6%" ry="6%" width="30%" height="30%"  />
        <rect x="1%" y="16%" rx="0%" ry="0%" width="84%" height="82%"  />
        <polygon points="17% 20%, 90% 20%, 75% 59%, 1% 59%" />
        </g>  
   </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

The same  file converted to a PNG is displayed as intended, but I would prefer to use the scalable graphic.

Comment: the % sign is invalid in polygon points attribute. You need to use user units and scale as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for that quick answer :-) - I will give it a go. Do you know why there is this limitation (which seems to apply only to browsers)?

Comment: I removed the percentage symbols and it works almost perfectly - just need to adjust the points for the right-hand edge :-)

Comment: The limitation exists because the SVG Specification says so. I don't know why the specification was written that way.